# The Breuil-Mezard Conjecture and Generalizations (Survey)

Tags: nt.number-theory, local-fields, p-adic-hodge-theory

What's the current state of the Breuil-Mezard conjecture? Has the original version (from the 2002 paper) been solved in its entirety? What are some of the new directions being explored?

Comment: have you checked out [On the Breuil-Mézard conjecture](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1422627050) ?-- it's a 2015 paper, so I would think that gives the state of the art...

Comment: I saw that paper, but I wanted to hear about the generalizations for the n-dimensional case. 

Also, in the 2-dimensional case, there seem to be some minor conditions placed on the representation, so I wanted someone to clarify that as well.